# Computing block systems for non-transitive permutation groups.

Tags: group-theory, gap, computer-algebra-systems, computational-algebra, magma-cas

Atkinson as well as Schönert and Seress describe methods to compute the minimal block system for transitive permutation groups; in particular in *Permutation Group Algorithms* by Ákos Seress, we find

> **Theorem 5.5.1** Suppose that a set S of generators for some transitive $G \leq Sym(\Omega)$ is given and $|\Omega| = n$. Then a minimal block of imprimitivity can be computed [...] by a deterministic algorithm.

Is there a way to compute such block systems for non-transitive permutation groups?

I have not found anything in the literature about such a computation.

Comment: You just go through all orbits of $G$, one by one and compute block systems for each orbit.

Comment: I am once again mystified by the vote to close.

Comment: @ahulpke, thank you for your reply. However, I am afraid I do not totally understand.

Comment: I think you need to say exactly what it is that you do not understand.

Comment: @DerekHolt, thank you. How does one compute block systems for each orbit? An orbit is just a set.

Comment: The group acts transitively on each orbit and, as you said yourself in your post, you can use the method in Seress' book to find minimal blocks in that case. You could also use the earlier algorithm of Atkinson, which has worse complexity, but is easier to understand.

Comment: @DerekHolt, thank you. I think this is the answer to my question.